# How does setting a string property trigger an action on DOM, change location etc. in a browser?

Tags: javascript, dom

For example if you set `location.href` or `iframe.src` or **`document.body.style.color"`** etc. something happens. Browser reports the type of these properties as string. I know there is properties in Javascript, but its new and this behavior was there ages before. How do browser implement this and can we do the same without implementing properties?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [WHATWG HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#the-location-interface), each `Document` object in a browsing context's session history is associated with a unique instance of a `Location` object. The `Location` interface supports the `URLUtils` interface, which makes the `href` attribute available, setting which on the `Document` object is equivalent to simply setting the latter.

Internally, the `location` attribute of the `Document` interface has an `assign(url)` method, which is called when a new location is set, which resolves the URL, if possible navigates to it and so forth.

Essentially and shortly put, `location.href` exposes the browser's internal navigation logic (the same that is used when you type an URL in the address bar) so that you can navigate to a given URL from your script. When you set it, you're not interacting with another script, you're working with an interface that's built into the browser.

How specific browsers implement it depends entirely on the developer, many large browsers (Chrome and Firefox) are open-source so you can inspect their code if you're interested.

Comment: i pretty much know what document.location is and does, this doesnt answer my question. see my edit

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest The answer for all the other properties is the same, they're interfaces provided by the browser.

Comment: then href and most of properties are actually methods but typeof operator reports its return type and they are used like a filed-property? then  apperantly browsers threat their objects differently. thats is what im asking, not history of href or navigitation stuff

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest Internally yes, setting `location` calls a browser's internal method, much like a custom setter, however from the front-end point of view they're still properties, that is, you can't modify the method that gets called or interact with it in any other way besides setting a new value to the property.